# Using open-uri with proxy, Non-HTTP proxy URI error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, proxy, open-uri

This works:

```
Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.website.com", :proxy => "http://IP1:PORT1"))
```

but this doesn't work:

```
Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.website.com", :proxy => "https://IP2:PORT2"))
```

The second call returns an error: `RuntimeError: Non-HTTP proxy URI.` I know for a fact that IP2:PORT2 is a proxy that supports https.

Any clue as to what's going on here? Is there any additional parameter I need to include in my open call to specify the protocol? I was under the impression that open would parse the protocol from my proxy string.